# nodejs http-server, can't connect localhost

Tags: node.js, npm, httpserver

I am using nodejs `http-server` for a web application. I am able to launch the `http-server` by running `nom start`. I can access my server through `http://127.0.0.1:8080` but I can't connect by `http://localhost:8080`. I have checked that `localhost` can be ping from my terminal and `localhost` works fine with other server such as `tomcat`. So I think the problem relates to `http-server` only. Is there any configuration I need to setup on my application in order to support `localhost` access?

Comment: Could you provide your code please? Try making your code connect to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: Node.js doesn't control how host names get resolved. That's an OS setting in `/etc/hosts` (on Linux)

Comment: They said pinging localhost works fine, meaning that, I can assume, `127.0.0.1 localhost` exists in the `/etc/hosts` file

Comment: Questions about code MUST include the relevant code.  Show us your server code, particular the `.listen()` part that starts your server.

Comment: Thank you for all. There is only an html file in root directory. There is no node server. The command I am using is `http-server -a 0.0.0.0`